# Event IDs for event log source "ASP.NET 2.0.50727.0"?

Tags: asp.net, event-log, event-id

When I create an entry in the Application event log with source "ASP.NET 2.0.50727.0" and Event ID 0, the following text is added to the top of the entry's text:

> The description for Event ID 1310 from
>   source ASP.NET 2.0.50727.0 cannot be
>   found. Either the component that
>   raises this event is not installed on
>   your local computer or the
>   installation is corrupted. You can
>   install or repair the component on the
>   local computer.
>
> If the event originated on another
>   computer, the display information had
>   to be saved with the event.
>
> The following information was included
>   with the event:

Where do I learn what event IDs *can be found*?  Put another way, where do I learn what event IDs I'm allowed to use?

Comment: I use this event source when I need to write to the log and have no other source registered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the [Event code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.management.webeventcodes(VS.80).aspx) can help you.

Also some codes are [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650306.aspx):
http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/Ff650306.f01paght00001601(en-us,PandP.10).gif

Comment: Thank you.  I tried using WebEventCodes.WebErrorConfigurationError in my WriteEntry() call, but I got text similar to that in the question.  I don't want to have to guess about this.  I want to know which event IDs will work.